# Submit form without page reloading, and link to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have made a system that when you enter a specific value, it'll fade in values based on the selection.

I have this code here which is the main form where you can input the specific model numbers into the form and then press enter.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="ModNum" id="ModelNumber" pattern="^PIV13RT[23]?$"
 title="Your Model Number." placeholder="Please Input a Model number" size="35" maxlength="8">
   <center><span class="egsmall"><strong>Eg: PIV13RT, PIV13RT2, Ect.</strong></span></center>
   <center><div class="btnwrap"><input name="proceed" type="submit" class="submitsup" id="forward" /></div></center>
</form>
```

The problem is that when you press enter, because it's inside of a form, it reloads the page, which means that the fade in won't load because it's reloading the page.

```
$("#forward").click(function(){ 
$.ajax({
}).done(function() {
  $('.optionbk').fadeIn('slow');
});   
});
```

I realise that this can also be done with Javascript, but that wouldn't allow me to use a Form.

```
$("#forward").click(function(){ 
    var text = $("#ModelNumber").val();
    var comparingText = "PIV13RT";
    var comparingText2 = "PIV13RT2";
    var comparingText3 = "PIV13RT3";
    if (text == comparingText) {   
$('.optionbk').fadeIn('slow');
    }
        if (text == comparingText2) {   
$('.optionbk').fadeIn('slow');
    }
            if (text == comparingText3) {   
$('.optionbk').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Is there anyway that I can do it inside of a form, but make it so that the page doesn't reload itself so that the fade works instead of reloading. The form is needed because it is following that specific pattern. Please note that the form isn't linking to an external PHP file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest solution is to add `onsubmit="return false"` into your opening `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You should bind your callback function to the submit event that the form dispatches and make it return false to cancel the actual submission.

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(){
    $.ajax();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This does the same thing as the previous answer except with javascript. What if JS was disabled on the client's browser?

Comment: Neither solution would work if javascript was disabled. The important thing is that my solution catches the event that will be dispatched on form submission, no matter how it was triggered (click, keyboard, scriot...)

Comment: The onsubmit does the same thing - it catches the submit event and returns false, preventing the page reloading.

Comment: yes but the ajax call will not be triggered if the user presses enter in the form. My solution uses a single callback handling the ajax call and canceling the form submission.

Comment: Test it - both solutions work, however the form is submitted. The onsubmit catches enter as well.

Comment: I agree, both solutions work. And your solution is the quickest. And it was accepted. I'm just saying that using a single callback may be a better practice. You have every right to disagree.